# Telerik ToDataSourceResult method causes NotSupportedException in oData DataServiceQuery

Tags: odata, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik data grid hooked up to this controller (which performs an oData query to the Microsoft Dynamics 365 cloud service)

```
    [Route("orders")]
    public ActionResult Orders([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var context = _dynamicsContextFactory.CreateContext();

        var orderHeaders = context.SalesOrderHeadersV2//TODO: filter to account for user's session// .Where(x => x.OrderingCustomerAccountNumber == "DE-001")
            .Select(
                x => new OrderHeader()
                {
                    SalesOrderNumber = x.SalesOrderNumber,
                    OrderTotalAmount = x.OrderTotalAmount,
                    SalesOrderOriginCode = x.SalesOrderOriginCode,
                    CustomerTransactionSettlementType = x.CustomerTransactionSettlementType,
                    OrderCreationDateTime = x.OrderCreationDateTime,
                    ConfirmedShippingDate = x.ConfirmedShippingDate,
                });
        // this way does not work with the ToDataSourceResult which performs paging etc.    
        //  x => x.AutoMap<OrderHeader>());

        return Json(orderHeaders.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Pagination works ok, but when I try grouping or sorting I get the following exception:

> The orderby query option cannot be specified after the select query option.

It seems like I need to re-order how the DataServiceQuery is constructed, but I have no idea how.
(If I made my API conform to oData specification and used [telerik's special handling for odata](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/odata) would that help? or just move the same problem elsewhere.)

**Extra info:**
I'd like to get automapper to work also, and I expect the root cause is similar.
Here's my View:

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyAccountApiController.OrderHeader>()
          .Deferred()
          .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(x => x.SalesOrderNumber);
              columns.Bound(x => x.CustomerTransactionSettlementType);
              columns.Bound(x => x.ConfirmedShippingDate);
              columns.Bound(x => x.OrderCreationDateTime);
              columns.Bound(x => x.OrderTotalAmount);
              columns.Bound(x => x.SalesOrderOriginCode);
          })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 400px;" })
          .Scrollable()
          .Groupable()
          .Sortable()
          .Pageable(page =>
              page
                  .Refresh(true)
                  .PageSizes(true)
                  .ButtonCount(5)
          )
          .DataSource(source =>
              source
                  .Ajax()
                  .Read(read => read.Action("Orders", "MyAccountApi")
                  )
                  .PageSize(20)

          ))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: The following answer works, but would perform badly because it does not push the projection to Dynamics and hence downloads a lot of data.**

I stumbled across the answer:

```
    [Route("orders")]
    public ActionResult Orders([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var context = _dynamicsContextFactory.CreateContext();

        var orderHeaders = context.SalesOrderHeadersV2;

        return Json(orderHeaders.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => new OrderHeader()
            {
                OrderCreationDateTime = x.OrderCreationDateTime.DateTime,
                SalesOrderNumber = x.SalesOrderNumber,
                CustomerRequisitionNumber = x.CustomerRequisitionNumber,
                SalesOrderStatus = x.SalesOrderStatus,
                DeliveryAddressLocationId = x.DeliveryAddressLocationId,
                ContactPersonId = x.ContactPersonId,
                OrderTotalAmount = x.OrderTotalAmount,
            }));
    }
```

or using automapper

```
    [Route("orders")]
    public ActionResult Orders([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var context = _dynamicsContextFactory.CreateContext();
        var orderHeaders = context.SalesOrderHeadersV2;
        return Json(orderHeaders.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => x.AutoMap<OrderHeader>()));
    }
```